# can application and hardware interact directly

Tags: operating-system

I am a new student studying OS course. I have already know that OS can serve for better communication between applications and hardwares in modern computer. But sometimes it seems more time efficient if applications can control hardware directly. May I ask whether it is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Could you give an example? @MartinJames

Comment: no - I would not do it.  I commented that is was possible, not that I thought it was a good idea.   Look at OpenGL and DirectX, maybe.   Only video acess makes any kind of sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible but that would be a single application computer that computer only can run one particular application.

Answer (score 0):

Applications handling hardware directly is faster as there is less of overhead of what OS does in its management.

You can take the example of DMA - Direct Memory Access. This feature is useful at any time that the CPU cannot keep up with the rate of data transfer, or when the CPU needs to perform work while waiting for a relatively slow I/O data transfer.

But you should keep in mind the importance of operating system in handling other hardwares as not everything can be managed that trivially and need processing for decision making.

Comment: DMA is not typically used from user applications.  It's a bulk I/O hardware subsystem that is typically managed via an OS.  DMA completion is usually signaled by an interrupt and is only sanely manageable from a OS driver.

Comment: Only initiation and receiving interrupt indicating end of DMA access involves its intervention. Its not a completely independent one though.